# Change a Dataframe timeseries such that it only contains the most updated value based on a changes log table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, series

Hello everyone and thank you for all your help.
I am trying to replace the old values on a time series based on a log table that recorded all the changes to each particular column, values might have changed multiple times.
One has three columns with values that change over time.

[image]

The second table recorded the changes to the columns of the first table, it  contains the old values the new values ones on separate columns it also has the dates when those values were changed.
[image]

What I am trying to accomplish would look like this,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### One line solution is this:

```
df['new_value'] = df.merge(changes, how = 'left')['new_value'].\
fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(df.old_value)
```

#### In details:

First create sample DataFrame with the initial values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2017-01-01', \
'2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05'],\
'old_value': ['AAA','AAA','AAA','AAA','AAA']})
```

```
        dates old_value
0  2017-01-01   AAA
1  2017-01-02   AAA
2  2017-01-03   AAA
3  2017-01-04   AAA
4  2017-01-05   AAA
```

And a DataFrame with changes:

```
changes = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2017-01-02','2017-01-04' ],\
 'new_value':['BBB', 'CCC']})
```

```
        dates new_value
0  2017-01-02       BBB
1  2017-01-04       CCC
```

Now join changes with to original DataFrame:

```
df = df.merge(changes, how = 'left')
```

```
        dates old_value new_value
0  2017-01-01       AAA       NaN
1  2017-01-02       AAA       BBB
2  2017-01-03       AAA       NaN
3  2017-01-04       AAA       CCC
4  2017-01-05       AAA       NaN
```

Then fill NA's from top to down using forward NA fill:

```
df['new_value'] = df['new_value'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

```
        dates old_value new_value
0  2017-01-01   AAA           NaN
1  2017-01-02   AAA           BBB
2  2017-01-03   AAA           BBB
3  2017-01-04   AAA           CCC
4  2017-01-05   AAA           CCC
```

Finally, fix beginning of the timeline with the original values:

```
df['new_value'] = df['new_value'].fillna(df.old_value)
```

Result:

```
        dates old_value new_value
0  2017-01-01   AAA           AAA
1  2017-01-02   AAA           BBB
2  2017-01-03   AAA           BBB
3  2017-01-04   AAA           CCC
4  2017-01-05   AAA           CCC
```

Comment: Dennis, thank you so much for your response. However what I am trying to accomplish is the opposite of what your solution is for. I have a table with values that are constantly changing across time and need to replace those old values with the most recent values.

Comment: Please host cab files somewhere or create a colander shared notebook